# Angular directive for entering only digits in text field is slow in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="phone_number" data-numbers-only="numbers-only">
```

**Directive**

```
App.directive('numbersOnly', function() {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == undefined)
          return ''
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }

        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Above is a phone number field in which by using angularjs directive I am restricting the user to enter only digits. If user tries to enter alphabets, its not at all visible in the input textbox.

The above works perfectly fine in Chrome and Mozilla, but when I checked it in IE 10 or Edge, though it is restricting the user to enter only digits but I can see a blur effect in input field, that means if user trying to enter alphabets they are visible for a short time and again they disappear. Its like show/hide.

The above issue is not happening in Chrome and Mozilla.

**"Is it because directives/JavaScript events are slow in IE/Edge"**

Any help is appreciated.